# How to remove part text from a column?

Tags: r, dplyr, gsub

I have a date value stored as a string in the following format: (`Day_of_week` `Month` `Day`, `Year`). I would like to remove the day of the week so the  final format is: (`Month` `Day`, `Year`)

```
mydata <- data.frame(Date=c("Tuesday, September 19, 2017",
                            "Friday, April 20,2018"),
                     Date_Exp=c("September 19, 2017",
                                "April 20,2018"))
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What is *day of the day*? Please show your attempt at solving it to clear out the issue.

Comment: I want to remove day of the week that is given in my column "Date" ....Like Tuesday should be removed from "Tuesday, September 19, 2017" .. I want only "September 19, 2017"

Comment: Yes, I see, your task is clear. So, what is the question?

Answer (score 3):

as @Wiktor Stribiżew said.. ur task is clear but couldnt get the purpose.
However this could solve ur problem:

```
format(as.Date(mydata$Date,format = "%A, %B %d, %Y"), format="%B %d %Y")
[1] "September 19 2017" "April 20 2018"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `gsub` we can remove any number of characters followed by "," and space from the beginning of the date.

```
mydata$Date <- gsub("^[a-zA-z]+, ", "",mydata$Date)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could keep your dates as character strings and then use regex to remove the day of the week:

```
vec <- c("Tuesday, September 19, 2017", 
         "Friday, April 20,2018")

trimws(sub("^.*?,","",vec))

#[1] "September 19, 2017" "April 20,2018"
```